# How to authenticate to influxdb when using k6

Tags: influxdb, k6

I am using k6 for as a load testing tool and I want to write data to influxdb. It all works fine except I do not know how to send user credentials for influxdb.

Example:

```
./k6.exe run --out "influxdb=http://localhost:8086/stresstest" script.js --vus 10 --duration 3s
```

I tried to pass influxdb username and password like this, but it doesn't work

```
./k6.exe run --out "influxdb=http://localhost:8086/stresstest?u=<USERNAME>&p=<PASSWORD>" script.js --vus 10 --duration 3s
```

I do not want to disable influxdb auth!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass them as HTTP auth in the InfluxDB URL like this: `--out "influxdb=http://<username>:<password>@localhost:8086/stresstest"`

Alternatively, you could also specify them via the `K6_INFLUXDB_USERNAME` and `K6_INFLUXDB_PASSWORD` environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My password is = pass@word. I tried replacing @ with %40 in password but still not working. Any thoughts on this are appreciated. I am running k6 tests at local but my InfluxDB setup is at Azure cloud.